# Error on hyperlink in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, hyperlink, azure

I take a url that works fine entering it manually in a browser, and  make a hyperlink from it on an Excel sheet. Then I click on that hyperlink in Excel. It goes to the browser but goes to an error url.

Here's the hyperlink:

```
https://ocpinsights.azurewebsites.net/?tab=2_1
```

I've also tried simplifying it to this:

```
https://ocpinsights.azurewebsites.net
```

Both of those work fine if I enter them manually in the browser. But when I put them in Excel as hyperlinks, and click on them, it turns into this url in the browser:

```
https://ocpinsights.azurewebsites.net/Error/Error?aspxerrorpath=%2FHome%2FAuthorize%2F
```

What can I do to make it work?

Comment: most likely the a new user session that is not signed in may be redirected by the site

Comment: @datatoo, I see now that the web page authenticates me automatically when I manually browse to it. Is it possible to do that from Excel?

Comment: Your browser session uses a different instance and likely excel is using a completely different one. Sorry I don’t know but that is likely the area to research